# Detect one-way road from origin_id and destination_id

Tags: openstreetmap, geopandas, graph, networkx, geosciences

How do I detect the one-way roads?

I have a graph G( MultiDiGraph(G) with origin(Id) and destination(Id) nodes. I would like to detect one-way roads. Example if there is an edge from the origin "1" to destination "2" and another edge from the destination "2" to the origin "1", then this is not a one-way road. And a column should be added to the edges table of this graph called oneway (boolean).

```
 G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(edges,'origin', 'destination',                              
 ['key','id_edge', 'name', 'lanes','length', 'speed', 'capacity', 
 'function', 'oneway', 'geometry'], 
                              create_using=nx.MultiDiGraph())
```

For detection one-way roads, I have tried this (but doesn't work):

```
oneway = []
for u, v, data in G.edges(keys=False, data=True):
    for a,b, data2 in G.edges(keys=False, data=True):
        if u==b and v==a:
            oneway.append(True)
        else:
            oneway.append(False)
```

For the column that should be added, I tried this:

```
edges['oneway']=edges.apply(lambda x: False, axis=1)
```

[image]

Comment: for any link (s, t) I want to know if there is a link (t, s) (i.e., there is a link in the opposite direction)